# How to determine the language set for a published workshared Revit model?

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

Our company has offices in both Germany and overseas.
Therefore our employees work on Revit models using both the German and English versions of the software.

We have found that the workshared models published to BIM360 have the language of their model derivates set to the language of the last Revit instance to save / synchronize the model.

As we are working with these model derivates, we are very interested in pre-emptively determining the language of the data.
The Version json data for the model obtained from the `GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents` endpoint doesn't appear to include the language the model was last saved in. 
Is there anything we missed with regards to determining the language of the model derivative data before obtaining it (and determining the language from the data itself).

Alternatively, having the option to specify the desired language upon requesting the data from the API using the `GET :urn/metadata/:guid` and `GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties` endpoints would be the best, and most proper, solution.

Comment: With my experience, the language depends on the last saving language. I'm double-checking with our engineering team, and will get back A.S.A.P.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Forge API doesn't support such a feature currently after checking with our engineering team. So, I summited a wishlist item **RVTLMV-1692** on your behalf for adding [i18n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) support on the Revit built-in properties. You're welcome to track the updates or provide us additional information via sending an email quoting the RVTLMV prefixed id to Forge Help email alias in the future. Cheers!